# Do i need separate JRE for my dual boot laptop?

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm

i am new to java and i have a dual boot laptop.I want to know that do i need separate JRE for the two OS ? If i need separate one , is this means that the bytecode translated by JVM is dependent only on the type of OS and not on the underlying architecture?As,it is the duty of the OS to deal with hardware not of JVM , is this true?

Answer (score 2):

Each OS needs its own version of every program, JRE (and JDK) included.

The JRE talks to the OS which talks to the underlying hardware.

Comment: this means my last line is true..?

Answer (score 0):

In dual boot system each operating system has required softwares installed in its own environment.
So if you require java (JRE and JDK) in both OSes you have to install java in both of the operating systems even though both are same OS( Windows-Windows).

JVM creates an environment for running same java program on any platform(whether linux or windows or any other OS) but for different platforms different versions of JVMs are there. 
Now when java program runs on your system it interacts with JVM, then JVM interacts with OS and then OS executes it on the processor. 
JVM are not hardware dependent, they are platform dependent.